# I have two span tags in a button, here the problem is those two span tags are behaving like a block element?

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am working on a Reactjs project, for that I am using the Bootstrap framework for designing. In that I have one div, in that div I have One button, In that button I have two Span tags. In first span tags I have Icon and In Second Span tag I have text. My problem is In output the text is coming under the Icon, But what I am expecting is Icon and text should be side by side. So try to help me to debug this issue.

This is App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './Navbar/Navbar';
import FlightsButton from './FlightsButton/FlightsButton';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FlightsButton></FlightsButton>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is App.css

```
There is no css in App.css
```

This is FlightsButton.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './FlightsButton.css'
import ReusableButtons from '../ReusableButtons/ReusableButtons';


class FlightsButton extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='container-fluid'>
                <div className='row'>
                    <div className='col-12'>
                        <div className='one mt-3 d-inline-block'>
                            <button type='button' className='buttonOne rounded-top'>
                                <span className='flightStyle'>
                                    <i class="fa fa-fighter-jet fa-sm flightLogo"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span className='flightContent pl-2'>
                                    Flights
                                </span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div className='two mt-3 d-inline-block'>
                            <ReusableButtons>
                                <span className='hotelStyle'>
                                    <i class="fa fa-bed fa-sm hotelLogo"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span className='hotelContent pl-2'>
                                    Hotels
                                </span>
                            </ReusableButtons>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default FlightsButton
```

This is FlightsButton.css

```
.buttonOne {
    background-color: #008ca8;
    border: none;
    padding: 0.50%;
    padding-left: 0.50%;
    padding-right: 0.50%;
}

.flightLogo {
    color:white;
}

.hotelLogo {
    color:white;
}

.hotelContent {
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Roboto,Oxygen,Ubuntu,Cantarell,Fira Sans,Droid Sans,Helvetica Neue,Arial,sans-serif;
}

.flightContent {
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Roboto,Oxygen,Ubuntu,Cantarell,Fira Sans,Droid Sans,Helvetica Neue,Arial,sans-serif;
}

.one {
    margin-right: 1%;
    /* display: inline-block; */
}

.two {
    /* display: inline-block; */
}
```

This is ReusableButtons,js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './ReusableButtons.css';

class ReusableButtons extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='buttonUsage'>
                <button type='button' className='customButtonStyle rounded-top'>
                    {this.props.children}
                </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ReusableButtons
```

This is ReusableButtons.css

```
.customButtonStyle {
    background-color: #00b2d6;
    border: none;
    padding: 0.50%;
    padding-left: 0.50%;
    padding-right: 0.50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of react but I used only HTML and CSS from your code and checked it. It looks fine.
But still, if you facing the problem, then increase the button width this will help you.